# How to get collection of invoices of a customer?

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, invoice

I am using below code but it is giving error please help.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento did not save `Customer id` on `Sales_flat_Invoice` table so If you want to  filter the  invoice Collection using customer id  and you need to MySQL join with `Sales_flat_order` table

**Step1:** Get Invoice resource Collection

```
  $collection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection');
```

**Step2:** add sales_flat_order table to collection.In magento, `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_invoice` table related with `Invoice table order_id and  sales_flat_order  table entity_id`

```
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$select->joinLeft(array('order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id=main_table.order_id', array('customer_id' => 'customer_id'))
```

Now You  can filter invoice collection by customer id

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code live? `'Can't retrieve entity config: sales/flat_order'` is the error I receive when trying to do so.

Comment: check now.... Can please tell me,Is your system file have table prefix

Comment: `'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.Id'` - and no, I don't have table prefixes.

Comment: please check now

Comment: Looks to work now, third time's a charm. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not store the `customer_id` column in `sales_flat_invoice` which is where the collection is found. It does however store the `order_id` field, so the following approach works 100%:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id);
$order_ids = array();
foreach ($orders as $order){
    array_push($order_ids,$order->getId());
}
$collection = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('in'=>$order_ids));
```

- The first four lines of code assemble the `order_id` which belong to the customer.
- The fifth line simply filters the invoice collection by those `order_id` values.

Voila!